# First time creating a website with Flask, I keep coming up with 'Error: No such command 'init-db' when creating a database

Tags: python, flask

I'm following [this tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/#tutorial), but have still managed to mess it up. Go figure.

Done everything up to the third page where we create the database. I know init-db is the correct format, I have installed flask within the venv,  and I have no idea where I went wrong.
Edit: I have done the exports
db.py

```
import sqlite3
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext


def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db


def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))


@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    #clear the existing data and create new tables
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')


def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

**init**.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass


    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello World'

    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

and schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;

CREATE TABLE user (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE post (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES user (id)
);
```

complete error code:

(venv) root@pi:/home/pi/flaskr# flask init-db

Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Try 'flask --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'init-db'.

Comment: Is `click` module installed?

Comment: I'm not sure, so probably not. so pip install click?

Edit nvm already installed

Comment: Did you already set the FLASK_APP environment variable? E.g.: `export FLASK_APP=flaskr`?

Comment: Yes. export FLASK_APP=flaskr and then export FLASK_ENV=development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. This took a while for me to recreate, however I have figured it out.  You are in the wrong directory in your terminal.  flask init-db needs to be ran from pi not flaskr... this is assuming that your venv environment is in pi.

Comment: You are brilliant!